# Maven не подгружает зависимости springframework/spring-core/ старше версии 4.3.0.RELEASE

Tags: spring, maven

Почему то maven отказывается подгружать зависимости от сюда
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-core/
старше 4.3.0.RELEASE

почему так может быть?
idea пишет
Dependency 'org.springframework:spring-core:5.0.0.RELEASE' not found more...

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

 <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Maven Plugin Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<pluginRepository>` используется для скачивания Maven плагинов, так что его добавление никак не влияет на поиск обычных зависимостей.

В зависимостях ты указываешь, что ищешь `4.3.0.RELEASE`, так что ничего удивильтельного, что 5.0 не скачен.

Comment: на 5.0 если заменить то не качает в этом был вопрос.

Comment: Ну тогда имеет смысл написать 5.0 в вопросе. И добавить какая ошибка вылетает если запустить `mvn install` в командной строке.